# my do while loop isnt meeting both requirements

Tags: c, cs50

When I am trying to get the input for my variable, it is only meeting one of the requirements (ie: the `< 1` requirement) and skips the other requirement even though im using the `&&` operator.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    do {
        x = get_int("what is the height of the pyramid?:");
    } while (x > 0 && x < 8);
    printf("%i", x);
}
```

I tried just using the `x < 8` for the requirement but it still went through when I entered `9`, `10`, `11` etc.

Comment: I don't see a `x < 1` case in your code. Could you give a particular input and explain how it deviates from your expectations?

Comment: *"it still went through when i entered 9, 10, 11"* - what do you think the expression `(x > 0 && x < 8)` evaluates to when `x` is `9` ? I'm nearly certain your condition is completely the opposite of what you want. Write it down, substituting `9` for `x`, and then think about it a moment. is `9 > 0` true ? Yup, What about `9 < 8` ? Um....

Comment: An alternate writing is to write the condition in the order of an inequality. You want to loop when `x` is outside of a valid range. So your condition is `(x < 1 || 8 < x)` for the valid integer input of `1` to `8`.  By writing `(x < 1 || 8 < x)` instead of the equally valid and correct, `(x < 1 || x > 8)`, etc.. you can easily look at the condition as looping any time `x` is *outside* the range of `1 -> 8`. You can write it however you like, but if it helps, structure your condition the same way you would find it written in a linear algebra class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `x` to be *between* 0 and 8 (both ends exclusive), then you need to repeatedly ask for input when this condition is *not* satisfied.

In other words, when `x` is outside this range it means `x` is less than or equal to 0 **OR** greater than or equal to 8.

That said, I believe the proper input range for that problem set is actually 1-8 (both ends inclusive):

```
do {
    x = get_int("What is the height of the pyramid?: ")
} while (x < 1 || x > 8);
```

Comment: In other words (like WhozCraig said above): the OP's code is doing the exactly *OPPOSITE* of what he probably intended.

Answer (score 0):

The test is exactly the opposite of your intent. The `do`/`while` condition should test a condition for repeating the input and write `while (!(x > 0 && x < 8));` or equivalently: `while (x < 1 || x >= 8);`

It is unclear what your requirements are, but it seems the number should be between `1` and `7` inclusively. If `8` should be included, the test should be modified as `while (!(x > 0 && x <= 8));` or equivalently: `while (x < 1 || x > 8);`

`do`/`while` loops are often confusing and error prone. I suggest using a `for(;;)` aka *for ever* loop and `break` statements when conditions are met:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    for (;;) {
        x = get_int("What is the height of the pyramid? ");
        if (x == INT_MAX) {
            printf("Input error or end of file\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if (x > 0 && x < 8) {
            break
        }
        printf("The height should be between 1 and 7\n");
    }
    printf("%i\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```